# Remove padding from tinymce table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Hi everybody I'm developing a CRUD system for a back-end webapp, I've installed `tinymce` and in the edit page I put the script for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
 height: 200,
 theme: 'modern',
 plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
 toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold underline italic strikethrough | backcolor forecolor | fontselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table ',
 toolbar2: 'numlist bullist | outdent indent | removeformat | subscript superscript | link unlink',
 fontsize_formats: '7px 8px 9px 10px 11px 12px 13px 14px 15px 16px 17px 18px 19px 20px 21px 22px 23px 24px 25px 26px 27px 28px 29px 30px',
 image_advtab: true
});
</script>
```

The problem is in the table plug-in, when I select `cellspace` and `cellpadding` from the editor it works, and seems save it correctly, but when I go in the view page of that element the table don't have that attributes. when I go in the developer tools in chrome I see:

```
th, td {
  padding: 0
}
```

And if I disable that the table goes in the right dimension...
Anyone can tell me what is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it looks correct in TinyMCE but not when rendered outside the editor its likely the CSS of your page is causing that change.  This appears to be the case based on what you state about the `th` and `td` padding in the dev tools.

Comment: yes you're right thanks, im trying to seek thath th, td that is making me crazy :)